# Deploy RabbitMQ along with Consul on Minikube cluster

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, minikube, consul

I currently try to deploy my learning environment. My goal is to deploy stack with Consul, Vault, RabbitMQ/Kafka, Jaeger, Elasticsearch, Prometheus, Grafana etc.
I am new to Kubernetes, Helm and networking stuff at all although I have experience with docker and swarm.

I successfully deployed Consul using that link: https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/kubernetes-minikube

Then I tried to deploy RabbitMQ and a faced problem. Rabbit's pod hangs in state **Init: CrashLoopBackOff** after few restarts.

Logs:

```
kubectl logs rabbitmq-0 consul-connect-inject-init -f  
...
2021-08-26T15:17:27.954Z [INFO]  Unable to find registered services; retrying
2021-08-26T15:17:28.955Z [INFO]  Unable to find registered services; retrying
2021-08-26T15:17:28.955Z [INFO]  Check to ensure a Kubernetes service has been created for this application. If your pod is not starting also check the connect-inject deployment logs.

kubectl describe svc rabbitmq
Name:              rabbitmq
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/instance=rabbitmq
               app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
               app.kubernetes.io/name=rabbitmq
               helm.sh/chart=rabbitmq-8.20.3
Annotations:       meta.helm.sh/release-name: rabbitmq
               meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Selector:                app.kubernetes.io/instance=rabbitmq,app.kubernetes.io/name=rabbitmq
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.104.42.222
IPs:               10.104.42.222
Port:              amqp  5672/TCP
TargetPort:        amqp/TCP
Endpoints:         
Port:              epmd  4369/TCP
TargetPort:        epmd/TCP
Endpoints:         
Port:              dist  25672/TCP
TargetPort:        dist/TCP
Endpoints:         
Port:              http-stats  15672/TCP
TargetPort:        stats/TCP
Endpoints:         
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

I also applied some changes to Rabbit Helm chart:

```
extraPlugins: "rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap rabbitmq_peer_discovery_consul"
cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend  = consul
cluster_formation.consul.svc = rabbitmq
cluster_formation.consul.svc_addr_auto = true
cluster_formation.consul.svc_addr_use_nodename = false
cluster_formation.consul.host = consul
cluster_formation.consul.use_longname = true
```

I used: https://www.rabbitmq.com/cluster-formation.html#peer-discovery-consul
With no effect.

Consul discovers Rabbit service, but pod is not working properly:
[Consul screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WmRM.png)

What can I do to resolve my problem?

Comment: are you aware about https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/operator-overview.html ?

Comment: Hi @user16760586, did you try solution posted above? Which Kubernetes version are you using? How exactly did you deply RabbitMQ?